# Why ListView expand/collapse animation appears much slower in DialogFragment than in Activity

Tags: android, performance, listview, animation

Recently, I find out the `ListView` expand/collapse animation appears much slower in `DialogFragment` than in `Activity`.

**In `DialogFragment`, the animation FPS is 10 fps. Each animation takes 100ms.**

**In `Activity`, the animation FPS is 50 fps. Each animation takes 20ms.**

I took this wonderful open source library as benchmark example : https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

I made modification on https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulationexamples/ItemManipulationsExamplesActivity.java#L51, to test between performance in `DialogFragment` and `Activity`.

```
    public void onExpandListItemAdapterClicked(View view) {
        // For Activity testing.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExpandableListItemActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        // For DialogFragment testing.
        //FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        //DemoDialogFragment demoDialogFragment = new DemoDialogFragment();
        //demoDialogFragment.show(fm, "DemoDialogFragment");        
    }
```

I made a minor modification on https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/example/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulationexamples/ExpandableListItemActivity.java

```
public class ExpandableListItemActivity extends MyListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyExpandableListItemAdapter myExpandableListItemAdapter = new MyExpandableListItemAdapter(this, getItems());
        //AlphaInAnimationAdapter alphaInAnimationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(myExpandableListItemAdapter);
        //alphaInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(getListView());
        getListView().setAdapter(myExpandableListItemAdapter);

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.explainexpand, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I created my own `DialogFragment` class for testing. Based entirely from `ExpandableListItemActivity`

```
package com.haarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulationexamples;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.haarman.listviewanimations.ArrayAdapter;
import com.haarman.listviewanimations.R;
import com.haarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.ExpandableListItemAdapter;

public class DemoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mListView = new ListView(getActivity());
        mListView.setDivider(null);

        MyExpandableListItemAdapter myExpandableListItemAdapter = new MyExpandableListItemAdapter(getActivity(), getItems());
        //AlphaInAnimationAdapter alphaInAnimationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(myExpandableListItemAdapter);
        //alphaInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(getListView());
        getListView().setAdapter(myExpandableListItemAdapter);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.explainexpand, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity())            
        .setView(mListView)
        .create();

        return dialog;
    }

    public ListView getListView() {
        return mListView;
    }

    protected ArrayAdapter<Integer> createListAdapter() {
        return new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), getItems());
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> getItems() {
        ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            items.add(i);
        }
        return items;
    }

    private static class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

        private Context mContext;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> items) {
            super(items);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return getItem(position).hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
            if (tv == null) {
                tv = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            }
            tv.setText("This is row number " + getItem(position));
            return tv;
        }
    }

    private static class MyExpandableListItemAdapter extends ExpandableListItemAdapter<Integer> {

        private Context mContext;
        private LruCache<Integer, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

        /**
         * Creates a new ExpandableListItemAdapter with the specified list, or an empty list if
         * items == null.
         */
        private MyExpandableListItemAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> items) {
            super(context, R.layout.activity_expandablelistitem_card, R.id.activity_expandablelistitem_card_title, R.id.activity_expandablelistitem_card_content, items);
            mContext = context;

            final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

            // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
            final int cacheSize = maxMemory;
            mMemoryCache = new LruCache<Integer, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
                @Override
                protected int sizeOf(Integer key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                    // number of items.
                    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight() / 1024;
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public View getTitleView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
            if (tv == null) {
                tv = new TextView(mContext);
            }
            tv.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.expandorcollapsecard, getItem(position)));
            return tv;
        }

        @Override
        public View getContentView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            if (imageView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            }

            int imageResId;
            switch (getItem(position) % 5) {
            case 0:
                imageResId = R.drawable.img_nature1;
                break;
            case 1:
                imageResId = R.drawable.img_nature2;
                break;
            case 2:
                imageResId = R.drawable.img_nature3;
                break;
            case 3:
                imageResId = R.drawable.img_nature4;
                break;
            default:
                imageResId = R.drawable.img_nature5;
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageResId);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), imageResId);
                addBitmapToMemoryCache(imageResId, bitmap);
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            return imageView;
        }

        private void addBitmapToMemoryCache(int key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
                mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
            }
        }

        private Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(int key) {
            return mMemoryCache.get(key);
        }
    }

}
```

Then, I place my benchmark code in this file : https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/library/src/com/haarman/listviewanimations/itemmanipulation/ExpandableListItemAdapter.java#L277

```
    private ValueAnimator createHeightAnimator(int start, int end) {
        Log.i("CHEOK", start + " -> " + end);
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mContentParent.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = value;
                Log.i("CHEOK", "height = " + value);
                mContentParent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
        return animator;
    }
```

Here is the result I'm getting

```
// Using DialogFragment
10-12 03:36:05.695: I/CHEOK(29407): height = 0
10-12 03:36:06.258: I/CHEOK(29407): height = 0
10-12 03:36:06.347: I/CHEOK(29407): height = 74
10-12 03:36:06.547: I/CHEOK(29407): height = 358
10-12 03:36:06.621: I/CHEOK(29407): height = 360



// Using Activity
10-12 03:37:02.375: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 0
10-12 03:37:02.387: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 0
10-12 03:37:02.406: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 3
10-12 03:37:02.461: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 51
10-12 03:37:02.476: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 72
10-12 03:37:02.492: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 98
10-12 03:37:02.512: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 131
10-12 03:37:02.531: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 164
10-12 03:37:02.547: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 196
10-12 03:37:02.562: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 228
10-12 03:37:02.582: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 260
10-12 03:37:02.601: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 290
10-12 03:37:02.617: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 312
10-12 03:37:02.633: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 331
10-12 03:37:02.652: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 348
10-12 03:37:02.672: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 357
10-12 03:37:02.687: I/CHEOK(29956): height = 360
```

Is there any idea, why this happens? How we can improve the performance in `DialogFragment`?

I place the entire project files, just in case you're interested to test out.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q6ttn11o92g39n/ListViewAnimations-master.zip

### Update

By tracing using TraceView, I notice that when using `DialogFragment` to expand `ListView` item, the `ArrayAdapter` will be called frequent. I'm not exactly sure why it is so. I do another independent implementation without using the open source library. I'm still facing the same problem.

**Perform animation on `DialogFragment`, the `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView` will be triggered frequently while animation is in progress.**

**For Activity, when animation is in progress, `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView` will NOT be triggered.**

**TraceView while using DialogFragment**
[image]

**TraceView while using Activity**
[image]

Comment: What did Traceview point out?

Comment: You must use profilers. What are the methods that run 5 times slower?

Comment: This is a guess, but I suspect that the animation causes the size of the ListView to change, which in turn causes a relayout. Not a problem in the Activity, since the ListView takes the full screen. Probably a problem in a Dialog, since it wraps around its content view. Try setting the height of the dialog ListView to a fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the key solution to this problem is, fix the dialog size always. Once we fix the size, no resource will be spent to perform size computation during animation.

```
    final ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Key area to perform optimization. Fix the dialog size!
            // During ListView's rows animation, dialog will never need to 
            // perform computation again.
            int width = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
            int height = dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

            ViewTreeObserver obs = view.getViewTreeObserver();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```